# Customizing as_json based on logged-in user's permissions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cancan

I'm working on a large rails multi-user application that supports different user roles. I'm using the devise and cancan gems to achieve this.

The problem that I'm having is that often, I would like for rails to respond with a json response that includes user-specific information. For example, the announcements/index.json uri should respond with a list of announcements as well as an integer for each announcement that specifies how many times the person has viewed the announcement (stored in a cross-reference table between users and announcements).

Another example occurs when administrators log in to the site; their json responses should often contain additional information to which regular users do not have access.

My question is what is the best way to do this? My original plan was to override as_json() for each model, and then check devise's current_user to determine what to produce. However, it is clear to me now that this is not an option, because the model in rails does not know about the currently logged in user.

Should I be doing this in the controller? I recently removed all of the old respond_to baloney that was fattening up my controllers (shown below), in favor of the more succinct respond_with.

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html
  format.xml { render :xml => @people.to_xml }
end
```

Do I need to return to this format, and make the distinction about which json to return in my controller? It almost feels like this should be a view concern, but I'm returning json, not HTML... Maybe I should do a json.erb file...

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I just found rails/jbuilder on github. Perhaps this is the solution to my problems.

Answer (score 1):

You can look at the decorator pattern:

http://nithinbekal.com/posts/ruby-decorators/

This will allow you to override as_json dynamically by wrapping the model object with different decorators based on the user's role.